# Can I map a key (caps lock) so it does one thing pressed alone, and another when pressed with a second key?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard

Just read this [seriously obsessive post about customising keyboards](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2012/10/a-modern-space-cadet/) and while I'm not going to do everything there, there are a couple of ideas I'd like to nick. In particular he has set up the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key so that:

- when pressed and released alone, it is mapped to <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- when pressed and held, and a second key is pressed, it is mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

As he says, this is great for vim users. Is that possible in Ubuntu?

He also does something similar with the right and left <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys. When pressed alone they map to <kbd>(</kbd> and <kbd>)</kbd> but if another key is pressed they act as you expect <kbd>Shift</kbd> to work.

Answer (score 4):

I found an [answer on unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31970/remap-capslock-to-escape-and-control-system-wide) at least to the Caps Lock/Ctrl/Esc part.

First remap Caps Lock to an extra Control by putting the following in `~/.profile`

```
if [ $DISPLAY ]
then
  # Add the 3 lines below to Convert caps-lock into Control
  xmodmap -e 'remove Lock = Caps_Lock'
  xmodmap -e 'keysym Caps_Lock = Control_L'
  xmodmap -e 'add Control = Control_L'

  # and xcape is in Startup Applications
fi
```

Then go get [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape) - you'll need to install the dependencies (see the README) and do `make` and `sudo make install`. And then it does what the README says:

> xcape runs as a daemon and intercepts the Control key. If the Control key is pressed and released on its own, it will generate an Escape key event.

I'm using it now and it's very nice :)

I guess a modified version could do the shift/parentheses thing as well.

Answer (score 2):

On **Ubuntu 16.04**

## 1st Option

### Caps_Lock as Ctrl

- open the file `/etc/default/keyboard`, and change `XKBOPTIONS=""` to:

  ```
  XKBOPTIONS="caps:ctrl_modifier"
  ```

### Caps_Lock as Esc

- install [xcape](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/xcape) with

  ```
  sudo apt install xcape
  ```
- create `.xsessionrc` at the home directory (or edit if it already exist)
- add the following line to `~/.xsessionrc`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  /usr/bin/xcape -e 'Caps_Lock=Escape'
  ```

### Note

- you need to logout then login.
- for a full list of all the options that you can set in (1), check the `! options` section in

  ```
  /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/*.lst
  ```

---

## 2nd Option

you can use the following script to get the same behavior in a session.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Super Caps

/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option 'caps:ctrl_modifier'  # rebind Caps_Lock to Ctrl, when held down, accomapgnied with other button
/usr/bin/xcape -e 'Caps_Lock=Escape'             # rebind Caps_Lock to Esp, when tapped alone
```

1. put the above content in a file, in any location

e.g. `custom_capslock` in `~/.local/bin/`

2. make it executable

   ```
    chmod a+x custom_capslock
   ```
3. add it to [Startup Applications](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html), by adding the FULL PATH of the script to Command field.

e.g `/home/yourname/.local/custom_capslock`

**PS:** if you want to use [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) or `/etc/rc.local` instead of "Startup Applications", make sure that your script didn't get overridden by other system services